# Django Development Server Page not loading

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to follow this tutorial for django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

I did the set up and I am trying to create a new page.

After starting the django server.

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I cant view the page in the browser. 
It says this page cant be displayed. But no error is shown at the djando command line terminal.

Comment: More info is needed. How are you trying to access it? Did you try the right port (usually 8000)? Wha't the full error message in the browser?

Comment: The page is not showing up. I tried accessing http://localhost:8000.. Tried with other ports too. But same result. No error is showing up in terminal.

Comment: After running `python manage.py runserver`, it should inform in which port it's running. Does it?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: It is showing 8000. I tried different ports too python manage.py runserver 6060. Like this

Comment: I am using IE browser

Comment: Try Chrome just for testing?

Comment: The weird this thing is that. It was working before. I closed the terminal and started again. It stopped working and no errors in python terminal!!!

Comment: Its coming up in firefox.. Anyone has any idea about the isue in IE??

Comment: @user2728024 IE probably doesn't map localhost to the IP of 127.0.0.1. So you should be able to access it from IE @ http://127.0.0.1:8000